# Упаковать Perl-проект с помощью PAR-Packer

Tags: perl

Добрый день!
Существует один проект — [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) — для работы с метаданными различного рода форматов файлов. Сам проект написан полностью на Perl.
Объясните, пожалуйста, как мне его упаковать с помощью [PAR-Packer](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-Packer-1.013/)?

Comment: Вопрос решен

Answer (score 2):

Статья об этом: [Perl — еще раз о деплое](http://habrahabr.ru/post/149586/).

Comment: я так и сделал.ю но без статьи